# Is this sentence a complete one?

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw this line in an online dictionary when I was checking the phrase trace out,

> The film portrays the legendary actor's rise to fame, tracing it out from his humble beginnings to.

Is this sentence a complete one? I feel that maybe there's something needed to be added after to.

Comment: It's not "something needs to be added". The word ***to*** shouldn't be there at all. Perhaps the writer initially *intended* to explicitly specify ***both ends*** of "the rise to fame" (from "humble beginnings" ***to*** "legendary actor"). But since that "end state" has already been mentioned earlier in the text, it makes no sense to repeat it. And the final text wasn't subject to proper proofreading.

Comment: Assuming that the "to" was intended to be there, and not an accidental slip, then some kind of complement is required, typically a noun phrase, e.g. "The film portrays the legendary actor's rise to fame, tracing it out from his humble beginnings to _his current iconic status in the film world_ ."

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on a typo

Answer (score 1):

I think that BillJ and FumbleFingers answered your question, but they did so in the comments, so I'll add an answer here. Every preposition generally requires an object (which is a kind of complement, as BillJ says). Your sentence ends with "to," which appears to function as a preposition, but it has no object. To fix the error, you can delete it or add an object after it.